# Case not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm importing a function with a case to avoid repeating the code and showing only some data.

The function is to avoid repeating the data and only import it when necessary without repeating all the options.

The code is this.

file import

```html
module.exports = {
  information: function (name, files, options) {
    case "send":
    console.log("is correct.")
        break;
  }
};
```

main code index

```html
const send = require('./options');

send.information("options", "others");


    switch (options) {
      send.information("test", "file1");
      send.information("test2", "other");
      send.information("test3", "other");
      default:
      console.log("Error option")
        break;
    }
```

And it tells me that case is not declared, but I don't know how I can declare when splitting the switch in half

Error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'case'

It's a rookie mistake but I'm just starting with the import and exports.

Comment: What you're trying to do is not allowed by the language. The `case` labels must be directly in the body of the `switch`, not in other functions.

Comment: Can you post a working code with all the repetition, please? Then we can help you making it DRY.

Comment: @Pointy I thought that it could be imported since it will be used within a switch

Comment: No, that's not how the language works.

Comment: @BergiThe code that I have provided is functional. I am working in nodejs, I import the document and mention the function, but according to the colleague, I cannot declare it outside the switch, although it is going to be used inside a switch.

Comment: @Pointy And is there an alternative that should not create such extensive cases in some way importing them? According to the need?

Comment: No, there is not. A `switch` statement and all of its `case` clauses must be in the same context. If you don't like that, don't use a `switch`; use separate `if` statements or something like that.

Comment: @Pointy That was why I had thought to use if, or to put a switch inside another so that this error did not occur.